# Flatlist won't show array from API

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm showing some API data, and some extra details in a seperate screen. In the detailscreen however, it's not showing the array which is in the API. It does show other data in the same screen, it just won't show the array.

```
export default class DetailsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const Order = this.props.route.params.order;
    const Name = Order.naam;
    const Adres = Order.adres;
    const Pizzas = [Order.bestelling];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> {Name} </Text>
        <Text> {Adres} </Text>
        <FlatList
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          data={Pizzas}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <Text> {item.Pizza} </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
        <Text>Pizzas</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is some JSON from the API I'm using. The data after "bestelling"(order) is what the flatlist won't show. I'm trying to show the list of pizzas. I have also tried just `{item}` instead of `{item.Pizza}`.

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "naam": "F. Christophe",
            "adres": "Eindje 1",
            "postcode": "5611 ZW",
            "bestelling": [
                {
                    "Pizza": "Salami"
                },
                {
                    "Pizza": "Calzone"
                },
                {
                    "Pizza": "Calzone"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "naam": "F. van Mulken",
            "adres": "Rechtestraat 5",
            "postcode": "5611 GL",
            "bestelling": [
                {
                    "Pizza": "Siciliane"
                },
                {
                    "Pizza": "Margarita"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "naam": "L. van  Beurden",
            "adres": "Keizersgracht 19",
            "postcode": "5611 GC",
            "bestelling": [
                {
                    "Pizza": "4-Stagione"
                },
                {
                    "Pizza": "4-Stagione"
                },
                {
                    "Pizza": "4-Stagione"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "naam": "M. Roozen",
            "adres": "Oude Stadsgracht 125",
            "postcode": "5611 DJ",
            "bestelling": [
                {
                    "Pizza": "Margarita"
                },
                {
                    "Pizza": "Calzone"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `Pizzas` the var you are passing to the `data` field. Is it the JSON object you have shown as is? If not, can you post what is `Pizzas` and I can help you further from there.

Comment: Yes just as it is, I take it out of the API and use it straight like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new array by using `[Order.bestelling]`, your Pizzas array becomes `[[...]]`.

```js
const bestelling = [
  {
    Pizza: 'Salami',
  },
  {
    Pizza: 'Calzone',
  },
  {
    Pizza: 'Calzone',
  },
];

const Pizzas = [bestelling];

console.log(Pizzas);
```

Change `const Pizzas = [Order.bestelling];` to the following

```
const Pizzas = Order.bestelling;
```

Comment: omg that was it, how was I that stupid to not notice that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A think you forget to add `keyExtractor` property in [FlatList](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) component

```
export default class DetailsScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const Order = this.props.route.params.order;
    const Name = Order.naam;
    const Adres = Order.adres;
    const Pizzas = [Order.bestelling];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text> {Name} </Text>
        <Text> {Adres} </Text>
        <FlatList
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
          data={Pizzas}
          keyExtractor={item => item.Pizza}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              <Text> {item.Pizza} </Text>
            </View>
          )}
        />
        <Text>Pizzas</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it still won't show anything, it just gives a warning saying "Each child in a list should have a unique 'key' prop"

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the `Pizza` property wrongly.

The way the data is coming. The pizza property will be in the array `item.bestselling`, you will then have to map over this array to show/render it.

Try adding this to the renderItem:

```js
 renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <View style={{ width: "100%" }}>
              {item.Pizza.map(data=> {
                 <Text>{data.Pizza}</Text>
              })}
            </View>
          )}
```

Comment: It gives an error saying "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.Pizza.map')"

Comment: Looks like it's solved. I thought you were passing the whole API data to your flatlist, which you weren't, it was being processed beforehand.

Comment: Thank you anyway